# angular 4+ - import modules globally for testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngx-translate

I'm just getting started writting unit tests for angular. As I am using ngx-translate in literally every component (and some services) I wanted to ask if there was a way to import and provide it on a global testing level.

So far I have provided and imported the ngx-translate module and http-loader in each .spec file like this

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

describe('AppComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientModule,
                TranslateModule.forRoot({
                    loader: {
                        provide: TranslateLoader,
                        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                        deps: [HttpClient]
                    }
                }),
            ],
            declarations: [
                AppComponent
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* provide it on the global testing level although it's intended to be imported and provided *per module* as that's in the spirit of Unit Testing.

Depending on your configuration you should have a `configuration-test.module.ts` where you bootstrap your `TestBed` with the `appInjector`, if you provide services in that module they will be provided for all `describe()` tests but you will still need to inject them manually in your components.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in your global test.js setup file were you call `initTestEnvironment`.

You can add a custom module there, something similar to

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      YourTestingModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: YOUR_TOKEN, useValue: 'yourValue'},
    ],
})
class GlobalTestingSetupModule {}

TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
    [
        BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
        GlobalTestingSetupModule,
    ],
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
    {},
);
```

example taken from: https://developapa.com/angular-jest-karma-config/

Comment: Shouldn't YourTestingModule be `exported` instead of imported in GlobalTestingSetupModule? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unit-testing-examples-x8j6ce?file=src%2Ftest.ts

Comment: the export is not needed for the testing. this is only relevant for stuff within a library.
And just to document this here as well, same example works with a standalone component instead of a module

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, could you give me a hint f.e. what did you change in the above stackblitz? Did you just get rid of GlobalTestingSetupModule and move all imports directly to initTestEnvironment?

Comment: you should have a main `test.ts` file that contains the `initTestEnvironment`. And there you can import a module that you want to have in each single test available

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I made in f.e. stackblitz above, but still without `exports` it doesn't work for me.